# Inserting empty verso pages in ‘book’

Tags: books, blank-page

I am writing a text that contains three parts (henceforth, *main body*) as well as two additional chapters: one before and one after (FC) the main body.

I want to separate FC from Part 3 with a completely blank page (or two) that do(es) not contain numbering and headers (although, I don't mind if the page is accounted for in the overall numbering) but **without the `openany` option** The problem is that the following does not really work as intended (the relevant part in **boldface**).

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ChapterOutsidePart}{%
   \def\toclevel@chapter{-1}\def\toclevel@section{0}\def\toclevel@subsection{1}}
\newcommand{\ChapterInsidePart}{%
   \def\toclevel@chapter{0}\def\toclevel@section{1}\def\toclevel@subsection{2}}
\makeatother
    \title{aaa}
    \author{aaa}
    \begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{alph}
    \maketitle
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \begin{center}
    \textit{This page was intentionally left blank.}
    \end{center}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \section*{Abstract}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
    \newpage
    \newpage
    \section*{0}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{0}
    \tableofcontents
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \ChapterOutsidePart 
    \chapter{1\label{ch:introduction}}
    \part{Part 1}
    \ChapterInsidePart
    \chapter{Chapter 2}
    \chapter{Chapter 3}
    \part{Part 2}
    \chapter{Chapter 4}
    \chapter{Chapter 5}
    \part{Part3\label{part2}}
    \chapter{Chapter 6}
    \chapter{Chapter 7}
    **\newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \begin{center}
    \textsc{End of Part III.}
    \end{center}
    \vspace*{\fill}**
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{1.5em}}
    \ChapterOutsidePart
    \chapter{Chapter 8}
    \end{document}
```

Namely, if the text of the preceding chapter ends at the verso, the blank page is inserted as recto. This creates an additional (verso) page (with a header and number, of course) after which the new chapter begins.

The twofold repetition of the code above does what is intended but seems a bit inelegant to me.

The question is whether it is possible to do something so that the end result is as follows.

- If the chapter preceding FC ends at the verso, **two blank pages** are inserted.
- If the chapter preceding FC ends at the recto, **one blank page** is inserted.

Or should I go with the simpler solution?

Comment: Please post full `MWE`

Comment: @MadyYuvi done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please create a tag as:

```
\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{\newpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}}
```

Whereever, you want an empty page, you should use `\clearemptydoublepage` instead of `\clearpage`, `\newpage`, or `\pagebreak`